# Converting datatable into JSON based on certain rules

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0, datatable

Class:

```
public class DataCls
    {
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public string Month { get; set; }
        public int MonthOrder { get; set; }
        public string category { get; set; }
        public int Val { get; set; }
    }
```

Data:

```
List<DataCls> dlist = new List<DataCls>();
            DataCls dat = new DataCls();
            dat.Year = 2015;
            dat.Month = "Jan";
            dat.MonthOrder = 1;
            dat.category = "A";
            dat.Val = 1;
            dlist.Add(dat);

            dat = new DataCls();
            dat.Year = 2015;
            dat.Month = "Jan";
            dat.MonthOrder = 1;
            dat.category = "B";
            dat.Val = 2;
            dlist.Add(dat);


            dat = new DataCls();
            dat.Year = 2015;
            dat.Month = "Jan";
            dat.MonthOrder = 1;
            dat.category = "C";
            dat.Val = 3;
            dlist.Add(dat);


            dat = new DataCls();
            dat.Year = 2015;
            dat.Month = "Feb";
            dat.MonthOrder = 2;
            dat.category = "A";
            dat.Val = 5;
            dlist.Add(dat);

            dat = new DataCls();
            dat.Year = 2015;
            dat.Month = "Feb";
            dat.MonthOrder = 2;
            dat.category = "B";
            dat.Val = 6;
            dlist.Add(dat);


            dat.Year = 2016;
            dat.Month = "Jan";
            dat.MonthOrder = 1;
            dat.category = "A";
            dat.Val = 4;
            dlist.Add(dat);

            dat = new DataCls();
            dat.Year = 2016;
            dat.Month = "Feb";
            dat.MonthOrder = 2;
            dat.category = "A";
            dat.Val = 7;
            dlist.Add(dat);

            dat = new DataCls();
            dat.Year = 2016;
            dat.Month = "Feb";
            dat.MonthOrder = 2;
            dat.category = "B";
            dat.Val = 8;
            dlist.Add(dat);

            dat = new DataCls();
            dat.Year = 2016;
            dat.Month = "Feb";
            dat.MonthOrder = 2;
            dat.category = "C";
            dat.Val = 9;
            dlist.Add(dat);

            dat = new DataCls();
            dat.Year = 2015;
            dat.Month = "Mar";
            dat.MonthOrder = 3;
            dat.category = "A";
            dat.Val = 10;
            dlist.Add(dat);
```

output I am expecting.

```
{
    "Series": [{
        "name": "A",
        "stack": 2015,
        "data": [1, 5, 10]
    }, {
        "name": "B",
        "stack": 2015,
        "data": [2, 6, null]
    }, {
        "name": "C",
        "stack": 2015,
        "data": [3, null, null]
    }, {
        "name": "A",
        "stack": 2016,
        "data": [4, 7, null]
    }, {
        "name": "B",
        "stack": 2016,
        "data": [null,8, null]
    }, {
        "name": "C",
        "stack": 2016,
        "data": [null,9, null]
    }]
}
```

points to remember:

1. `Year` property will be assigned to `stack` property in json object.
2. `Category` property will be assigned to `name` property in json object.
3. The number of  `Category` is not fixed.
4. A given  `Category` may or may not be present for a given month.
5. `val` property will be assigned to `data` array in json object for each month.
6. If the category is missing for a month, we need to consider the value as null.

I am really not sure how to go about this problem. How can I proceed to solve this problem.  I am having hard time fixing this.

Comment: Does it have to be a DataTable? Can you have an IDataReader instead?

Comment: @MattClark. Yes I can use DataReader as well. I initially thought I will use LINQ on top of DataTable & it would be easy to query the datatable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of linq to transform the data and then Json.NET to create the json.

```
  //here assuming monthMap is an int map
  // "Jan" => 1
  // "Feb" => 2
  // etc
  var lqOutput 
           = dbOutput
                .OrderBy(a=>monthMap[a.Month])
                .GroupBy(a=>new{a.Category,a.Year})
                .Select(a=>new{ 
                            name=a.Key.Category,
                            stack=a.Key.Year,
                            data = a.Select(b=>b.Val).ToArray()
                 });

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new{ Series = lqOutput});
```

If you wanted to have the months that do not show up be skipped you could make a smaller helper method

```
var dictToArr = new Func<int,Dictionary<int,object>, object[]>((size,d)=>{
        var retv = new object[size];
        foreach(var key in d.Keys)
        {
            if(key>=0)
            {
                retv[key] = d[key];
            }
        }
        return retv;
    });

var lqOutput 
        = dbOutput
                .OrderBy(a=>monthMap[a.Month])
                .GroupBy(a=>new{a.Category,a.Year})
                          .Select(a=>new{ 
                                      name=a.Key.Category,
                                      stack=a.Key.Year,
                                      data = dictToArr ( 12,
                                                a.Select(b=>new{ 
                                                            val= b.Val, 
                                                            idx=monthMap[b.Month]
                                                  }).ToDictionary(
                                                              b=>b.idx,
                                                              b=>b.val as object
                                                  ) )
                                  });

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new{ Series = lqOutput});
```

If you do this you need to map January to 0, Feb to 1, etc

Comment: I am getting error saying `Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type`

Comment: @OpenStack dbOutput is a collection of Dtos here, you need to cast them into objects for this solution to work... I don't know how you are pulling the data out of your database so this is the most I can help with at this point

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. I see what you are saying now. in the data array which you are creating, if value for any month is not present, currently we do not show it. Is there a way to tell if a value is not present for a month, show it as null.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am getting `An item with the same key has already been added.` error. looks like duplicate value is being added on the dictionary but I am not able to figure out what change I need to make to make it work

Comment: That means you have the same month two times in a year? Not sure how you want to handle that?

Comment: I have updated the question. I have included the data new class I am using. The input I am using and the output I am expecting. Please help

Comment: @OpenStack this is because of a bug in your code, you are not declaring a new value for the variable dat for the item after Feb 2015 Category B, but `dat = new DataCls()` on that line and it will work

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code I use to convert IDataReader to a class

```
public static List<T> DataReaderMapToList<T>(this IDataReader dr)
    {
        var list = new List<T>();
        var obj = default(T);

        var columns = dr.GetSchemaTable().Rows;
        var columnsArray = new DataRow[columns.Count];
        columns.CopyTo(columnsArray, 0);

        var columnNames = columnsArray.Select(x => x[0].ToString());
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

            var type = obj.GetType();
            foreach (var column in columnNames)
            {
                var field = type.GetField(column);
                if (field != null && dr[column].GetType().FullName == field.FieldType.FullName)
                {
                    field.SetValue(obj, dr[column], BindingFlags.SetField, null, null);
                    continue;
                }

                var property = type.GetProperty(column);
                if (property != null && dr[column].GetType().FullName == property.PropertyType.FullName)
                {
                    property.SetValue(obj, dr[column]);
                }
            }

            list.Add(obj);
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure if I follow what you are doing, I need to convert the data (either stored in datatable or custom object) into JSON.I also need to keep in mind rules I have mentioned. I just don't see a way this code can help me

Comment: @openstack You could edit this to apply your rules before you create the class, and then serialize your objects to json